# Difference between print string with parenthesis and without

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Python 2.7 (interactive mode), both:

```
print("Hey Joe")
```

and:

```
print "Hey Joe"
```

give output:

```
"Hey Joe"
```

What is the difference? When should I use the former and when the latter?

Thank you

Comment: `print "Hey Joe"` in python3 throws a syntax error. Are you on python2?

Comment: There is no difference. A string with parens around it is still just a string.

Comment: Use `from __future__ import print_function` and then it's just a function (to be used with parens) like in Python 3. But why on Earth are you still on 2?

Comment: Python 3 was released in 2008, and the final end of life of 2 is january 1, 2020 -- eleven months from now.

Comment: The one is called print statement and the other print function. Print function has been introduced with python 3 as print is really a function :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What is the difference?

Generally `print 'something'` is called print statement and `print("something")` is called print function. Print function has been introduced with `Python 3`. Other than that looking at the basic usage you won't notice any difference. However, you could find more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html).

> When should I use the former and when the latter?

If you want to make your code both Python 2.7 and Python 3 compliant than you should use print function, it is safe to import it with Python 2 and Python 3 it makes difference only with Python 2.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: On Python 2, unless you explicitly turn off the print statement with `from __future__ import print_function`, `print("something")` is still using the print statement. It's not the print function, as you can easily see when `print(1, 2)` prints a tuple and `print(1, file=whatever)` fails to parse.

Comment: You mean if you want to use print function on Python 2 always import it?

Comment: Technically, it's a compiler directive that disables the print statement, not actually importing the print function - the print function is always there, but inaccessible because of the statement's existence. Still, yes, use `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: @user2357112 tnx for the explanation. I wasn't aware how its internally works.